# Windows azure Session Management Configuration

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure

I m new to windows azure platform we are currently migration asp.net application to
    windows azure platform.In that we have instance count in that i using 2 instance.

```
the issues is when we set 2 instance count during login the site is not allowing to login 
for 1st attempt it allowing me to login after 2nd attempt at every page this is happening
but if i set only 1 instance in webRole config the site is working fine but i need to use
2 instance 
plz provide me link any configuration settings for session management can u tell what is 
of 2 instance 
i googled but i couldn't find any sorry for my engh
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because Windows Azure makes use of `Round Robin` load balancing and I'm assuming you're using `In-Proc` session state management. So in your case, your request goes to say "Instance 1" of your cloud service and you establish a session there. Now the next request goes to "Instance 2" of your cloud service and it does not have that session state.

To make this work with minimal changes to your code, I would recommend using `Windows Azure Cache` as the `Session State Provider` instead of `In Proc`. You may find this link useful for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx.

For some other options for managing session state, you may find this blog post useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/05/17/session-state-management-in-windows-azure-web-roles.aspx.

Comment: i have changed code according i m using sql azure for session management in that session table is created in that every row is creating in that when i create a session can u tell me how to clear that session table or is any issue with this approach thank you..

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used SQL Azure as session state provider thus I won't be able to comment however my guess is that once the session expires, the data should be cleared from the table. Is there any particular reason you are using SQL Azure instead of In Role Caching as session state provider? Using SQL Azure will introduce network latency and thus would be much slower than cache session state provider. HTH.

Comment: Can u brief me how to use In Role Caching after searching i found tht i need to pay for In role Caching plz correct me if i misunderstood tht and In role caching shud i change the code for sessions thank you

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx. This link has all the information you need. If you use in-role cache, then you don't pay anything extra. You are just allocating a part of your VM for caching purpose. However if you go with a dedicated role for caching, then you would pay for that role.

Comment: if i use In role Caching then the 2 instance problem will solve that

Comment: i configured as u said but i m getting error while i run the project its says "There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker for role instance "

Comment: i getting this error when i run project : Error: The installed Windows Azure Emulator does not support the role binaries. Please install the latest Windows Azure Emulator and try again.
Windows Azure Tools: The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service. Please see the release notes.I have latest emulator 2.1v

Comment: Looks like an issue with your development machine.

Comment: can u plz tell why i m getting this error "There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker for role instance http://255.0.0.1:80" im little bit in hurry

Comment: I have seen this error when I run my cloud service in IIS instead of IIS Express. Right click on your cloud project, click on Properties and see if IIS is selected. Try using IIS Express instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38715/discussion-between-light-and-gaurav-mantri)